# Creating a hosted console application in .NET 8.0

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, .net-8.0

The GenericHost/DefaultHost/WebHost ecosystem changes rapidly, and seems lacking for a combination of requirements.  I am using .NET 8.0.

Using stable packages as of Jan 2024, what does a console application look like that creates an application host, configures Logging/DI/Configuration, and waits for a single application loop to exit, while providing Ctrl+C support to gracefully terminate early?

Using the following code, I get "RunAsync done" followed by "stopped" on the console with a graceful shutdown.  If I attempt to break the fake 'work loop' with Ctrl+C, the application immediately exits with no graceful termination.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hostBuilder = CreateDefaultApp(args);
        var host = hostBuilder.Build();

        Console.WriteLine("starting");
        var app = host.Services.GetRequiredService<TestApp>();
        await app.RunAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("stopped");
    }

    private static IHostBuilder CreateDefaultApp(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();
        builder.ConfigureServices(conf =>
        {
            conf.AddSingleton<TestApp>();
        });
        builder.ConfigureLogging(conf =>
        {
            conf.ClearProviders();
            conf.AddConsole();
        });
        builder.UseConsoleLifetime();

        return builder;
    }
}

public class TestApp
{
    private readonly IHostLifetime _lifetime;
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _appLifetime;

    public TestApp(IHostLifetime lifetime, IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    {
        _lifetime = lifetime;
        _appLifetime = appLifetime;
    }

    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        var stopToken = _appLifetime.ApplicationStopping;

        Console.WriteLine("RunAsync starting");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (stopToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("STOP");
                break;
            }
            
            await Task.Delay(250);
            Console.Write(i);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("RunAsync done");
    }
}
```

I don't care if my application logic lives in this somewhat-standalone "TestApp" class, or runs as a Hosted Service, as long as it can get dependencies injected, can trigger its own graceful (and ungraceful) exit, runs in an `async` context, and can be relatively gracefully terminated early with Ctrl+C.  I am wanting to use the `Host` providers from Microsoft to get the bulk of the configuration done, and I don't want to "simply just" do all my own dependency management and configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your current code - you are setting up the host but not using it, you need at least to start and wait for it (basically you are listening for host stopping but it was not even started to be stopped):

```
var hostTask = host.StartAsync();
await app.RunAsync();
await hostTask;
```

Basically your current code looks like an attempt to create your own hosting utilizing the generic host DI infrastructure (though you can just use `ServiceCollection` if you only need the DI).

But better approach would be to use the [hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) (they are not ASP.NET Core specific, [worker service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers) template also uses them) for your `TestApp`.

Comment: oh damn it, just awaiting the hostTask got me nearly everything I was looking for.

Comment: @BryanBoettcher was glad to help! If any of the suggested answers works for you - feel free to mark it as accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a background worker (please see [Worker services in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers)) to achieve the behavior you want.

I've modified your code a bit. Please note that you need to change the project template to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker`

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateDefaultApp(args).Build();

        Console.WriteLine("starting");
        await host.RunAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("stopped");
    }

    private static IHostBuilder CreateDefaultApp(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();
        builder.ConfigureServices(conf =>
        {
            conf.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        });
        builder.ConfigureLogging(conf =>
        {
            conf.ClearProviders();
            conf.AddConsole();
        });

        return builder;
    }
}

public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _HostApplicationLifetime;
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _Logger;

    public Worker(IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime, ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _HostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
        _Logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("RunAsync starting");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("STOP");
                break;
            }

            await Task.Delay(250);
            Console.Write(i);
        }

        _Logger.LogInformation("test logging");

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("RunAsync done");
        _HostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
    }
}
```